# Registering of controls in web.config

Tags: web-config

Is it possible to register controls, aside from:

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="CustomSearch" Namespace="SomeAssembly.WebControls" 
   Assembly="SomeAssembly.WebControls, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

within the web.config file, like you can with a normal ASP.Net web site? I tried this, but SharePoint keeps complaining that it cannot find the control?

Comment: Are you trying to register some user control?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to register a variety of User Controls, you cannot do it that way. A user control requires that you reference it's `.ascx` file in order to use it, like this:

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="CustomSearch" Tagname="SearchBox" src="~/_controltemplates/customsearch/searchbox.ascx" %>
```

The above allow the use of this: `<CustomSearch:SearchBox ID="SearchBox1" runat="server" />`

Whereas in your provided example, that registers `controls`, which also will allow the use of the above example, but the difference being that the controls don't have "visual" files like `.ascx` or `.aspx`.

Comment: in my example these are server controls compiled in assemblies. I'm well familiar with this in ASP.net but for some reason, SharePoint does not like it?

Comment: @JadedEric Are you sure that the assembly is indeed in the GAC and that it is the correct assembly information that you type in the `<%@ Register %>`?

Comment: i did, check on several times even recompiled and resubmitted the assemblies to the GAC. it's very weird. will play around again to see if can get around it. thanks.